# Python ssl socket client request, Getting infinite wait on recv call

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to build a client in python with SSL and Socket libraries, but after sending the request with sendall, getting infinite wait on recv(1024) call.

```py
def auth(hostName, port, userName, password):

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      
    # wrap the socket with SSL
    sslContext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
    sslContext.load_verify_locations('C:/Users/<name>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Lib/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem')
    wrapped_sock = sslContext.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostName, do_handshake_on_connect=True)
    wrapped_sock.settimeout(None)
    # connect to a server
    wrapped_sock.connect((hostName, 443))
     # send a message
    req = {
        "command":"authenticate",
        "params":{
            "email_address": userName,
            "password": password
        }
    }
    r = json.dumps(req,ensure_ascii=True)
      
    try:
        rbytes = bytearray(r,encoding='ascii')
        wrapped_sock.sendall(rbytes)
        # receive a response
        response = wrapped_sock.recv(1024) # getting infinite wait here
        # print the response
        print(response)  # b''
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```